# How can I overwrite a file in use on a network drive?

Tags: overwrite, network-drive, file-in-use

I've created a desktop app that pulls images from a shared network drive where the end users have read-only access.  I need to update some of the images on the network drive but am getting errors regarding "file is in use by another process".

How can I identify the process using the image I need to replace, being that the process is likely my app running on someone else's machine, so that I can suspend that process just long enough to overwrite the file?  Once I do identify the process on that user's machine, how would I suspend it, overwrite the file, and "un-suspend" it? (Keeping in mind that there can be any number of users accessing the file at once (currently up to 20 but once the app goes "live" there could be 200+ users accessing the file at once...)

Any ideas?

Comment: Which OS are we talking about here?

Comment: It seems like you have some fundamental problems with your application architecture that is wasteful of system resources (not to mention preventing you from maintaining the files that the application uses). For example, why is the application holding on to the file handle in the first place? Oh, and @Timo Geusch is right, we need to know what OS we're even talking about, here.